# Using PLM in R for Panel Data

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I have a data set of employees who have worked at a company throughout 2017. The data set is broken out month by month; someone can work all 12 months of the year (12 rows) and someone can have worked for 3 months before leaving/getting terminated (3 rows).

I wanted to see if there was a relationship between termination rates (1 for terminated; 0 for still at the company) and department (1 for CA; 0 for US), but because this is panel data, someone suggested that I have to use the PLM package.

I tried doing a basic function like so:

```
fixed <- plm (Term ~ Canada, data = df, index = c("Month"), model = "within"
summary(fixed)
```

These were my results:

```
Unbalanced Panel: n = 12, T = 116-207, N = 1972
Residuals:
Min.  1st Qu.   Median  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-0.37179 -0.24446 -0.17718 -0.04075  0.95925 

Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)    
CANADA -0.084064   0.018344 -4.5826 4.882e-06 ***

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Total Sum of Squares:    320.25
Residual Sum of Squares: 316.85
R-Squared:      0.010606
Adj. R-Squared: 0.0045455
F-statistic: 21 on 1 and 1959 DF, p-value: 4.8822e-06
```

This is my first time using the PLM package, but based on the P-value, we rejet the null hypothesis and there is a significant difference between where you work (CA vs. US) and whether or not you leave.

Have I done this right? I ask especially to ensure I have chosen the correct model function. I ask because just looking at the data, American workers have only a slight termination rate higher than Canadian workers (mostly because there's a smaller total).

EDIT:

I've been informed that I should have used pglm.

I've tried something like this:

```
fixed <- pglm( Term ~ CANADA, data = df, na.action=na.omit, family = binomial(link = "logit"), index = "Fiscal.Period");
```

These are the results:

```
Estimates:
        Estimate Std. error t value  Pr(> t)    
(Intercept)  -1.0153     0.1458  -6.962 3.36e-12 ***
CANADA       -0.5200     0.1124  -4.625 3.74e-06 ***   
sigma         0.6048     0.1620   3.733 0.000189 ***
```

Comment: I think you need to worry a bit more about R-Squared:      0.010606 than you seem to be doing. There is always a question about how useful it is as a measure of anything much, but that has got to seem low without more evidence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a logit panel model instead, since that would constrain your outcome variable to fall between 0 and 1. For this, you need to use the function pglm(), which will require you installing the pglm package first. Off the top of my head, I think you need to specify the option, family = "binomial", in order to get a logit model, but double check this in the documentation. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Hey, someone suggested today that I use pglm instead of plm for this particular problem (0 - 1). I'm looking into the documentation now, and trying the "Fairness" data set but I would need help understanding the results there too.

Comment: Sure man, I'm happy to help. If my first reply answered your first question, could you mark it as an answer?

Comment: Done. I used pglm on the Fairness data set, but I don't understand what I am to make of the summary. What is the initial function value mean? And what do the initial gradient values mean?

Comment: Be careful: the example given using the Fairness data is an ordered probit example - the dependent variable can take 4 possible values. In your case, you need to use a binary logit model. Run the following code in R (posted in next comment) - I've created a new variable from "answer", that takes the value 0 if they answer 0 or 1, and 1 if they answer 2 or 3. I then run a logit model predicting this, using all other variables. The resulting regression table should be clear. Let me know if you need anything else. (Apologies for messiness; semicolons indicate the end of a command).

Comment: library(pglm);
data("Fairness");
Fairness[,"fair"] <- integer(nrow(Fairness));

for (i in 1:nrow(Fairness)){
  if (is.na(Fairness[i,"answer"])){
    Fairness[i,"fair"] <- NA
  } else if (Fairness[i,"answer"]=="2" | Fairness[i,"answer"]=="3"){
    Fairness[i,"fair"] <- 1
  }
};

mod <- pglm(fair ~ good + rule + driving + education + recurring, 
         data=Fairness, na.action=na.omit, family = binomial(link = 
logit"),
            index = "id");
summary(mod);

Comment: Hi notebook, thanks so much. Looking at the summary, most of them are significant. Where did sigma come from? Why does it only show some attributes of certain columns (goodparking) and not others (goodtgv)?

Comment: No worries man. Regarding the sigma - honestly I can't remember. It's not a coefficient, and I never worry about it... I think it's got something to do with the shape of the logistic curve, but don't quote me on it. Regarding the attributes, when there's a factor variable with $n$ factors, R automatically generates $n-1$ binary variables for each factor. So model variable "goodparking" = 1 if the observation reports "parking" for variable "good",  model variable "ruleadmin" = 1 if the observation reports "admin" for variable "rule", and so on.

Comment: I'm going to post in my question the results using my dataset. I don't understand what the results are telling me.